# PHP File Editing problems

Tags: php, iis, file-io, windows-7, webserver

I've been working with IIS and PHP recently, but can NOT edit files. I gave permission to edit the wwwroot file to IIS_IUSRS, but that does not seem to do anything. I'm still getting the following warnings:

```
Thanks for your request, *My IP Here* The robot moved forward. Warning: fopen(Ips.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CMD.php on line 20 Unable to open file, Ips.txtPermission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CMD.php on line 20 Unable to open file, Ips.txt
```

If I understand correctly, this means that the wwwroot is not open to php editing.
Here's my code:

```
<?php
$cmd=$_GET["cmd"];
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if($cmd=="Forward") {
//insert forward code here.
    echo "Thanks for your request, ".$ip." The robot moved forward.";

} else if($cmd=="Backward") {
//insert backwards code here.
    echo "Thanks for your request, ".$ip." The robot moved backwards.";
} else if($cmd=="Left") {
//insert left code here.
    echo "Thanks for your request, ".$ip." The robot moved left.";
} else if($cmd=="Right") {
//insert right code here.
    echo "Thanks for your request, ".$ip." The robot moved right.";
} else {
    echo "Got invalid command: ".$cmd." From IP: ".$ip;
}
$ipfile = fopen("C:/inetpub/wwwroot/Ips.txt",'w') or exit("Unable to open file, Ips.txt");
if(!strpos(file_get_contents("C:/inetpub/wwwroot/Ips.txt"),$ip)) {
    fwrite($ipfile,$ip);
}
echo "\nYour IP has been logged for security purposes.";
fclose($ipfile);
$log=fopen("C:/inetpub/wwwroot/Logs.txt",'w') or exit("Unable to open file, Logs.txt");
fwrite($log,"Got command, ".$cmd." from a computer at the adress, ".$ip);
fclose($log);
?>
```

I've looked around for quite a while, and have found similar situations, but the solution is either not found, or about improper IIS file permissions.

Comment: have you tried to add an absolute path in front of the filename?

Comment: You do `fopen("Ips.txt")` but `file_get_contents("/User/WebServer/Desktop/Ips.txt")` .. are those meant to be the same file?

Comment: oops, forgot to update that, and yes, i tried using an absolute path.

Comment: You really should use absolute paths, unless you're very certain what the current working directory is.

Comment: Fixed that, updated, no avail

Comment: `/C:/inetpub/wwwroot/Ips.txt` ... I don't think the leading slash should be there.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it turns out IPs.txt somehow lost permission for user editing, I added permission, and fixed the problem, thanks for all the help!